# Assignment of r-base plot to a value

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graphics

I've a problem with saving a r-base plot to an object. I want to assign whole plot which in fact consists of two plots merged by `layout()` function into a variable and then merge this plot with other by `ggarrange()` function. The `recordPlot()` function does not work cause I receive an error:

```
## Warning: Package `gridGraphics` is required to handle base-R plots.
## Substituting empty plot.

## Warning: Package `gridGraphics` is required to handle base-R plots.
## Substituting empty plot.
```

Here's the plot that I want to save:

```
layout(matrix(c(1, 2), 2, 1))
  hist(X1209_HCC1806_cv$Absorbance)
  boxplot(X1209_HCC1806_cv$Absorbance, horizontal = TRUE)
```

How does the gridGraphics package work? And how can I assign my plot to a variable in order to use it in `ggarrange()`?

Comment: have a look at the ggplotify package. https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/ggplotify/vignettes/ggplotify.html

Comment: You need to install the `gridGraphics` package. The error message is telling you that you currently don’t have this package installed, and therefore your code doesn’t work.

Answer (score 1):

[Claus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4975218/claus-wilke) is exactly right. You just need to install `gridGraphics` with `install.packages("gridGraphics")`. Your code worked perfectly for me.